# JavaScript OOP in NodeJS: how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, inheritance, mongoose

I am used to the classical OOP as in Java.

What are the best practices to do OOP in JavaScript using NodeJS?

Each Class is a file with `module.export`?

How to create Classes?

```
this.Class = function() {
    //constructor?
    var privateField = ""
    this.publicField = ""
    var privateMethod = function() {}
    this.publicMethod = function() {} 
}
```

vs. (I am not even sure it is correct)

```
this.Class = {
    privateField: ""
    , privateMethod: function() {}

    , return {
        publicField: ""
        publicMethod: function() {}
    }
}
```

vs.

```
this.Class = function() {}

this.Class.prototype.method = function(){}

...
```

How would inheritance work?

Are there specific modules for implementing OOP in NodeJS?

I am finding a thousand different ways to create things that resemble OOP.. but I have no clue what is the most used/practical/clean way.

**Bonus question**: what is the suggested "OOP style" to use with MongooseJS? (can a MongooseJS document be seen as a Class and a model used as an instance?)

**EDIT**

here is an example in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eS7LE/4/) please provide feedback.

```
//http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/
function inheritPrototype(childObject, parentObject) {
    var copyOfParent = Object.create(parentObject.prototype)
    copyOfParent.constructor = childObject
    childObject.prototype = copyOfParent
}

//example
function Canvas (id) {
    this.id = id
    this.shapes = {} //instead of array?
    console.log("Canvas constructor called "+id)
}
Canvas.prototype = {
    constructor: Canvas
    , getId: function() {
        return this.id
    }
    , getShape: function(shapeId) {
        return this.shapes[shapeId]
    }
    , getShapes: function() {
        return this.shapes
    }
    , addShape: function (shape)  {
        this.shapes[shape.getId()] = shape
    }
    , removeShape: function (shapeId)  {
        var shape = this.shapes[shapeId]
        if (shape)
            delete this.shapes[shapeId]
        return shape
    }
}

function Shape(id) {
    this.id = id
    this.size = { width: 0, height: 0 }
    console.log("Shape constructor called "+id)
}
Shape.prototype = {
    constructor: Shape
    , getId: function() {
        return this.id
    }
    , getSize: function() {
        return this.size
    }
    , setSize: function (size)  {
        this.size = size
    }
}

//inheritance
function Square(id, otherSuff) {
    Shape.call(this, id) //same as Shape.prototype.constructor.apply( this, arguments ); ?
    this.stuff = otherSuff
    console.log("Square constructor called "+id)
}
inheritPrototype(Square, Shape)
Square.prototype.getSize = function() { //override
    return this.size.width
}

function ComplexShape(id) {
    Shape.call(this, id)
    this.frame = null
    console.log("ComplexShape constructor called "+id)
}
inheritPrototype(ComplexShape, Shape)
ComplexShape.prototype.getFrame = function() {
    return this.frame
}
ComplexShape.prototype.setFrame = function(frame) {
    this.frame = frame
}

function Frame(id) {
    this.id = id
    this.length = 0
}
Frame.prototype = {
    constructor: Frame
    , getId: function() {
        return this.id
    }
    , getLength: function() {
        return this.length
    }
    , setLength: function (length)  {
        this.length = length
    }
}

/////run
var aCanvas = new Canvas("c1")
var anotherCanvas = new Canvas("c2")
console.log("aCanvas: "+ aCanvas.getId())

var aSquare = new Square("s1", {})
aSquare.setSize({ width: 100, height: 100})
console.log("square overridden size: "+aSquare.getSize())

var aComplexShape = new ComplexShape("supercomplex")
var aFrame = new Frame("f1")
aComplexShape.setFrame(aFrame)
console.log(aComplexShape.getFrame())

aCanvas.addShape(aSquare)
aCanvas.addShape(aComplexShape)
console.log("Shapes in aCanvas: "+Object.keys(aCanvas.getShapes()).length)

anotherCanvas.addShape(aCanvas.removeShape("supercomplex"))
console.log("Shapes in aCanvas: "+Object.keys(aCanvas.getShapes()).length)
console.log("Shapes in anotherCanvas: "+Object.keys(anotherCanvas.getShapes()).length)

console.log(aSquare instanceof Shape)
console.log(aComplexShape instanceof Shape)
```

Comment: There is nothing really _specific_ about OO JS in node.js. There is just OO JS. Your question is about _translating_ Java OOP techniques to JS, which is just _not right_. I think it better you spent the same time/energy in learning how JS's prototype-based model works, and how you can use it to your advantage

Comment: Also, you don't have classes in JavaScript. You can create class-like behaviour with functions, but it's generally not a good idea.

Comment: As for inheritance, every method declared in prototype will be accessible by instances of your "Class" object but also children of "Class".

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek you wrote **You can create class-like behaviour with functions, but it's generally not a good idea.** Can you please explain me why is that not a good idea?

Comment: I guess my question is how to do OOP in JS, then. What is the standard pattern? There must be public and private fields/methods, right? There must be some easy way to inherit, right?

Comment: @JJPA : Just like array subclassing in JavaScript, you can emulate classes but it's not a native feature so I wouldn't try to bend the language's tools to fit that style of programming. Especially if you are new to functional programming, loose-typing languages or JavaScript in general, there are a lot of little quirks and strange behaviours that you wouldn't anticipate while implementing classes like that. Like @ EliasVanOotegem explained, there's no real OO JS standard in Node.js and you should deal with it not try to circumvent it. This is just an opinion though.

Comment: @fusio : What you can do is split your code in different files. Any method that isn't exported with `module.export` is by default private.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek What do you mean by it is not a "native feature"?

Comment: Well classes don't exist in JavaScript's current version (ECMAScript 5). You could try to create some class-like functions, but it's not built-in the language. (EDIT: Classes will be added though in ECMAScript 6.)

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek when you use `new`, constructor funtions and prototypes naturally, the engines optimize that behind the scenes much like as if they were Java classes. When you clown around with dynamic closures, you make many optimizations impossible. How is that for native?

Comment: @fusio With prototypal inheritance in general, objects/instances inherit from other objects/instances. So, classes aren't used because you aren't working with abstract definitions. So, inheritance is done through a [`prototype` chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). And, no, object don't support "*private*" members. Only [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) can offer that, though modules/scripts in Node.js are implemented as closures.

Comment: @Esailija Behind the scenes, numbers are optimized to Ints if they are not floats / doubles, that doesn't mean that JavaScript has ints though. That's what I meant, not V8, not the engine, but the language itself.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski ? No they are not, they are implemented as I have shown in my answer, through natural object model of javascript. See https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/lib. Closures don't have private *members*, they are variables that cannot support any language level features that object properties support. Further, they enforce privacy which is not done in any other language so you have tremendous inflexibility.

Comment: @Esailija I didn't actually mean to suggest closures can create private members. Was just suggesting that closures and enclosed variables are [as close as you can get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures) in JavaScript. But, for the other part: the only "*implementation*" I mentioned regarded Node modules, which are evaluated within a closure where some of the [globals](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) are defined unique to each script.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You can get even closer to [access modifiers](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AccessModifier.html#AccessControlDoesNotControlAccess) with conventions like underscore prefixing. Closures unconditionally prevent access, which is not what access modifiers do.

Comment: @Esailija Underscore prefixing doesn't have any special meaning in JavaScript (as opposed to say Python). Such properties are still publicly accessible and can be tampered with (EDIT) *without reflection*. `console.log(new Animal(8)._age); // 8`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Private properties can be tampered with in Java too.  Read the link.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I didn't notice your edit until now. Why exactly does it matter if one has to use reflection to access private? You can access it if you want and that is the end of story. I mean you could argue that it is inconvenient but with a library and static imports it's `get(obj, "age")` vs `obj._age`. There only remains the argument that `._age` is more possible to write accidentally. As if there was a plausible scenario where one writes that and could honestly claim it was by accident. It is in the class of "I slipped and..." explanations...

Answer (score 120, accepted):

This is an example that works out of the box. If you want less "hacky", you should use inheritance library or such.

Well in a file animal.js you would write:

```
var method = Animal.prototype;

function Animal(age) {
    this._age = age;
}

method.getAge = function() {
    return this._age;
};

module.exports = Animal;
```

To use it in other file:

```
var Animal = require("./animal.js");

var john = new Animal(3);
```

If you want a "sub class" then inside mouse.js:

```
var _super = require("./animal.js").prototype,
    method = Mouse.prototype = Object.create( _super );

method.constructor = Mouse;

function Mouse() {
    _super.constructor.apply( this, arguments );
}
//Pointless override to show super calls
//note that for performance (e.g. inlining the below is impossible)
//you should do
//method.$getAge = _super.getAge;
//and then use this.$getAge() instead of super()
method.getAge = function() {
    return _super.getAge.call(this);
};

module.exports = Mouse;
```

Also you can consider "Method borrowing" instead of vertical inheritance. You don't need to inherit from a "class" to use its method on your class. For instance:

```
 var method = List.prototype;
 function List() {

 }

 method.add = Array.prototype.push;

 ...

 var a = new List();
 a.add(3);
 console.log(a[0]) //3;
```

Comment: what is the difference between using `Animal.prototype.getAge= function(){}` and simply adding `this.getAge = function(){}` inside `function Animal() {}` ? The sub-class seem a bit hacky.. with "inheritance" library you mean something like `inherits` as suggested by @badsyntax ?

Comment: @fusio yes, you can do something like `inherits(Mouse, Animal);` that cleans up the inheritance set up a bit. The difference is that you are creating new function identity for each instantiated object instead of sharing one function. If you have 10 mice, you have created 10 function identities (that is only because mouse has one method, if it had 10 methods, 10 mice would create 100 function identities, your server would quickly waste most of its CPU on GC :P), even though you will not use them for anything. The language doesn't have enough expressive power to optimize this away currently.

Comment: Woah. Thanks :) This seems quite simple, I also found [Details_of_the_Object_Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) where they compare JS with Java. Still, to inherit they simply do: `Mouse.prototype = new Animal()`.. how does it compare with your example? (e.g. what is `Object.create()`?)

Comment: @fusio Object.create doesn't invoke the constructor... if the constructor has side effects or such (it can do anything a normal function can, unlike in Java), then invoking it is undesirable when setting up inheritance chain.

Comment: Naming a variable 'method', which references the prototype, makes no sense at all.

Comment: @badsyntax well yes it does. It's word against word, what you gonna do?

Comment: I still maintain that for someone that is starting to use JavaScript, hacking a solution like this isn't a good solution. There are so many quirks and pitfalls that aren't easy to debug that this shouldn't be advised.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek Can you give an example then?

Comment: Yes, you subclass an array and break every `for ... in` loop or declare two methods with the same name at different places in the prototype chain and don't understand which one is called. There are many other use cases like this ...

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek That doesn't even make sense. Why would subclassing an array break `for..in` loop even if you were idiotic enough to use `for..in` for arrays?

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. If you create an Object called "MyGreatObject" that has an array's behaviour (constructor) + some added properties, you wouldn't be able to loop through them with `for ... in`. Also, if done wrong, some array subclassing implementations miss some of the array's native methods and behaviours. There are many blogs on this subject but this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek If this way has many pitfalls and quirks, why did you feel the need to come up with something like this as an example? Trying to extend a built-in is pretty hard-core thing to attempt and not advocated by me at all.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek could you give me an example of a non-hacky solution to create something structured as the following: a Canvas is an object that contains Shapes. A Shape is an object that can either be a ComplexShape object which contains a Frame object and a Material object, or a simpler shape (e.g. Rectangle object, Circle object, ..). In Java I would simply create a Shape class and then extend it to create the various Rectangle, Circle,..  and the ComplexShape class which would contain in its fields a Frame and a Material. Easy. In JS?

Comment: @fusio why don't you try to write that taxonomy in JS with what you have learned and show it to us and maybe we will see if you did something wrong.

Comment: @Esailija : I didn't say you were advocating it, but imo if fusio every encounters an example like this or tries to implement functionalities like these, it would most like be difficult to debug.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek in my experience in most questions the problem has been `this` binding with event handlers and unsurprisingly some people using variables thinking they are object properties, which I strongly advocate against with multiple researched reasons anyway. None of these problems are inherent with constructors and prototypes as shown in the answer. "Subclassing a built-in" is not an everyday activity or a common thing to do at all, so I feel surprised you make that as first example when there were supposed to be many pitfalls.

Comment: You can take a good sample here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop+javascript

Comment: @fusio looks good to me although you should have made a now post possibly on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. To answer your comment question, `_super.constructor.apply( this, arguments )` is more general than `Shape.call(this, id)`: it has no hardcoded constructor name and works for any number of arguments. Note that my method assumes Node.JS and unique file for each "class", the way it works on jsfiddle and with everything thrown together is different because the variables I make would be shared instead of being unique to each file.

Comment: Oh, cool! Did not even know existed something like that. Yes, indeed in Node it would be different.

Comment: This answer is outdated, better read https://stackoverflow.com/a/34847083/226958 below.

Answer (score 51):

As Node.js community ensure new features from the JavaScript ECMA-262 specification are brought to Node.js developers in a timely manner.

You can take a look at **JavaScript classes**. [MDN link to JS classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) 
In the ECMAScript 6 JavaScript classes are introduced, this method provide easier way to model OOP concepts in Javascript.

**Note** : JS classes will work in only **strict mode**.

Below is some skeleton of class,inheritance written in Node.js ( Used Node.js Version **v5.0.0** )

**Class declarations :**

```
'use strict'; 
class Animal{

 constructor(name){
    this.name = name ;
 }

 print(){
    console.log('Name is :'+ this.name);
 }
}

var a1 = new Animal('Dog');
```

**Inheritance :**

```
'use strict';
class Base{

 constructor(){
 }
 // methods definitions go here
}

class Child extends Base{
 // methods definitions go here
 print(){ 
 }
}

var childObj = new Child();
```

Answer (score 14):

I suggest to use the `inherits` helper that comes with the standard `util` module: http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

There is an example of how to use it on the linked page.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer with regards to the core NodeJS environment.

Comment: Looks now deprecated. From answer link: *Note: usage of util.inherits() is discouraged. Please use the ES6 class and extends keywords to get language level inheritance support. Also note that the two styles are semantically incompatible.*

Answer (score 13):

This is the best video about Object-Oriented JavaScript on the internet:

[The Definitive Guide to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfcsYzj-9M)

Watch from beginning to end!!

Basically, Javascript is a [Prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) language which is quite different than the classes in Java, C++, C#, and other popular friends.
The video explains the core concepts far better than any answer here.

With ES6 (released 2015) we got a "class" keyword which allows us to use Javascript "classes" like we would with Java, C++, C#, Swift, etc.

Screenshot from the video showing how to write and instantiate a Javascript class/subclass:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate you having provided an answer for ES6. Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't have the data to watch a 27 minute video. I'll continue my search for written guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the video. I helped me to clear lot of questions i had about javascript.

Answer (score 5):

In the Javascript community, lots of people argue that OOP should not be used because the prototype model does not allow to do a strict and robust OOP natively. However, I don't think that OOP is a matter of langage but rather a matter of architecture.

If you want to use a real strong OOP in Javascript/Node, you can have a look at the full-stack open source framework [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf). It provides all needed features for a strong OOP code (classes, interfaces, inheritance, dependency-injection, ...). It also allows you to use the same classes on both the server (node) and client (browser) sides. Moreover, you can code your own danf modules and share them with anybody thanks to Npm.

Answer (score -3):

If you are working on your own, and you want the closest thing to OOP as you would find in Java or C# or C++, see the javascript library, CrxOop. CrxOop provides syntax somewhat familiar to Java developers.

Just be careful, Java's OOP is not the same as that found in Javascript. To get the same behavior as in Java, use CrxOop's classes, not CrxOop's structures, and make sure all your methods are virtual. An example of the syntax is,

```
crx_registerClass("ExampleClass", 
{ 
    "VERBOSE": 1, 

    "public var publicVar": 5, 
    "private var privateVar": 7, 

    "public virtual function publicVirtualFunction": function(x) 
    { 
        this.publicVar1 = x;
        console.log("publicVirtualFunction"); 
    }, 

    "private virtual function privatePureVirtualFunction": 0, 

    "protected virtual final function protectedVirtualFinalFunction": function() 
    { 
        console.log("protectedVirtualFinalFunction"); 
    }
}); 

crx_registerClass("ExampleSubClass", 
{ 
    VERBOSE: 1, 
    EXTENDS: "ExampleClass", 

    "public var publicVar": 2, 

    "private virtual function privatePureVirtualFunction": function(x) 
    { 
        this.PARENT.CONSTRUCT(pA);
        console.log("ExampleSubClass::privatePureVirtualFunction"); 
    } 
}); 

var gExampleSubClass = crx_new("ExampleSubClass", 4);

console.log(gExampleSubClass.publicVar);
console.log(gExampleSubClass.CAST("ExampleClass").publicVar);
```

The code is pure javascript, no transpiling. The example is taken from a number of examples from the official documentation.