# javascript - class with data how to load

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to model a product in javascript:

```
var Product = {};
Product.getSku = function() {
    return this.sku;
}
Product.getPrice = function() {
    return this.price
}
Product.getName = function() {
    return this.name
}
module.exports = Product;
```

What is the correct way to create this object with the required properties?

Im coming from an oop background, am I thinking of js wrong?

Comment: have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript OOP in NodeJS: how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188083/javascript-oop-in-nodejs-how)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would you do in in OOP?

You'll probably have these choices:

- Via setters (you've already got getters).
- Via constructor.
- Via fields directly.

The first and the last are obvious.

In the second you'll probably do something like:

```
var Product = function(sku, price, name) {
    this.sku = sku;
    this.price = price;
    this.name = name;
}

var product = new Product(1, 2.34, "FiveSix");
```

A variation of this would be to pass an object as a single parameter:

```
var Product = function(data) {
    var productData = data || {};
    this.sku = productData.sku;
    this.price = productData.price;
    this.name = productData.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is this:

```
function Product(name, sku, price){
    this.name = name;
    this.sku = sku;
    this.price = price;
    this.getSku = function(){
        return this.sku;
    }
    this.getPrice = function(){
        return this.price
    }
    this.getName = function(){
        return this.name
    }
}

module.exports = new Product("book", "aa123bb456", 6.35);
```

There are other ways....

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.